# Remover tag do componente angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Existe alguma forma de renderizar apenas o conteúdo do componente, escondendo as tags?

Como funciona:

```
<ul>
    <li-component> </li-component>
</ul>
```

Renderiza:

```
<ul>
    <li-component>
        <li>
            Frase
        </li>
    </li-component>
</ul>
```

Ele mantém a tag do `<li-component>`

Resultado desejado:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Frase
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pode explicar o motivo de querer isto?

Answer (score 0):

**Bem vindo Glauco!** :D

Cara é bem simples você pode alterar o seletor do componente "**apesar de não recomendado**" no [Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#component-selectors)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'li[my-component]',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor() { }

}
```

Você pode usar basicamente um seletor de atributo apesar de ter outros seletores, ficaria assim:

```
<ul>
    <li my-component> </li>
</ul>
```

Renderizaria assim:

```
<ul>
    <li my-component>
        Frase
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Não funcionou aqui :(

Ele ainda renderiza a tag li, e outra tag li dentro

Comment: Coloque o seu componente de exemplo aqui! *.ts* *.html* e *.css*